# Photo stream and iCloud?

Tags: icloud, iphone

I have a new iPhone 4s and an account on iCloud. Is it possible to move an old photo album from my old iPhone 4 to the new iPhone 4S by just using iCloud?

Answer (score 1):

One way i can think of is using a Mac:

- Sync your old iPhone and download your photos to iPhoto.
- Activate iCloud and Photo Stream on your mac using your iCloud ID.
- iPhoto now will have a Photo Stream folder.
- Drag the desired photos/events to the Photo Stream folder in iPhoto.
- Make sure you have Photo Stream activated on your iPhone 4S and you are using the same iCloud ID on all related devices.
- iCloud on your iPhone 4S should detect via WiFi or your carrier that you have photos in your Photo Stream and will sync all devices under your iCloud ID.

I haven't managed to copy the photos to the Photo Stream Folder on the phone, so maybe it's not implemented yet, but one workaround if you don't have a Mac, is to email/message yourself the photos. Read the mail/message using your new iPhone 4S and save the photos. They will appear in the Photo Stream folder.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared photo stream with yourself, copy all the needed pictures into this album and access it again from the new iPhone. See [this cnet.com](http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57508640-285/how-to-create-a-shared-photo-stream-album-on-ios-6/) page for an explanation on how to create a shared photo stream.